# Background tabs loading incorrectly sized when Chrome starts up maximized

Tags: google-chrome

I just switched from Firefox to Chrome and noticed certain pages display funny when they're loaded on startup. Specifically, their horizontal size does not fill the Chrome window, like they're stuck at a pre-set size. This only happens when Chrome starts maximized, and page resizes correctly <s>when I hit reload or</s> if I restore Chrome window size and then maximize it again.

I also just noticed that if one of the problematic tabs has focus when Chrome starts, it does not have any issues loading. Only the background tabs cause problems.

I can't distinguish what content could be causing some windows to work properly and some to not. For example, Gmail loads correctly but not Google Finance.

Any ideas as to what is causing this?

EDIT: As it turns out, reloading the page does *not* fix the issue. I have to restore and then re-maximize **each broken tab** each time I start Chrome.

I've also confirmed that this is not due to any of the extensions I was using.

[image: Google Finance - One of the problematic pages in question]

Comment: I've seen this before, and all I do to fix it is reload the tab.

Comment: @RandolphWest See my edit. Reloading does not seem to fix it. It wouldn't bother me so much if it wasn't every single time it loaded. Most of these tabs that don't work are those I keep constantly up as pinned tabs, too. Bummer.

Comment: Same thing happens to me. Quite often. Usually after restarting browser. Reloading does not fix it. Re-maximisation does.